# OutputStreamWriter contains a path separator

Tags: java, android, streamwriter

Today i tested "files" instead of a normal path.
Here is my code:

```
File path=new File(getFilesDir(),"uf");
File test = new File(path.getAbsolutePath(),"test.txt");


if(!path.exists()){
    path.mkdir();
}

if(!test.isFile()){
    try {
        test.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO in errorlog -> filecreation
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}else{
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter mywriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(test.getAbsolutePath().toString(),Context.M                                                               ODE_PRIVATE));
        mywriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In the error code comes everytime: `illegal Arguments: contains a path seperator`!

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Always provide full exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add more info about your error. But...

This error is about that you are trying to full path (include you subdirectories) to access to private data area.
Solution is use `FileOutputStream`, more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). And use

```
new File(YOUR_FILE)
```

to create your file.

Keep on mind that you should call method `mkDirs()` to create all necessary directories and subdirectories. More about mkDirs() [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

Note: There is also method `mkDir()`, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) is doc. This one will create a single directory.